# Get JSESSIONID from HttpWebResponse in C# desktop application

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse, jsessionid

I've created this sample using MSDN examples.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(redirUri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
Trace.WriteLine("Created request to " + redirUri);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

// Right here I want to get JSESSIONID, but Cookies are empty

foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", cook.Name, cook.Value);
}
```

Cannot get JSESSIONID. I need to make several GET/POST queries in one session, that's why I need JSESSIONID.
Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

```
string cookieHeaderValue = ((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)response).Headers["Set-Cookie"].Split(new char[]{';'})[0].Trim();
```

Comment: In the future, please add a description to your post and not just code.  :)